# How to access a random image in a folder? Python

Tags: python

does anyone know how to access a random image in a folder?

What I am trying to do is have a random image show up after the user has made an input. The images are already stored in a folder that's loaded into PyCharm and have a file on my desktop.

I found this code below online, but I'm not 100% sure how to use it.

```
import os
import random 
path="C:\\Users\\sairajesh\\Desktop\\image"
files=os.listdir(path)
d=random.choice(files)
d.show
```

Any help here is appreciated!  You can see my error below. I'm using a Mac. Also, I'm new to programming so pls don't judge.

Here is the error I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kimtran/PycharmProjects/final/Where to eat.py", line 66, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/kimtran/PycharmProjects/final/Where to eat.py", line 45, in main
    files =os.listdir(path)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/kimtran/Desktop/pics'
```

Comment: What's not clear about the error? The path is wrong... Also, strings have no `show` attribute. I would recommend you to consider using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) instead of `os` methods related to paths.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work, except for the `d.show` I don`t know what you are trying to do with that. And your path is a windows path format not the one you have on your mac.

```
import os
import random
from PIL import Image

path = './imagefolder'  # in case the folder is in the same directory as the script
files = os.listdir(path)  # listdir gives you a list with all filenames in the provided path.
randomFile = random.choice(files)  # random.choice then selects a random file from your list
print(randomFile) #  prints the random filename

image = Image.open(path + '/' + randomFile)  # displayed the image
image.show()
```

Warning randomFile is just the filename as string and not the actual file.

Comment: Double backslashes are more correct than single backslashes, since they are the escape character used in Python strings: https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html . `path = r"C:\Users...` would be better, since the `r` makes it a raw string where backslashes are no longer an escape character.

Comment: Hi! Thanks! Can you show me what it's supposed to look like on a Mac? I didn't realize it was for Windows until after (noob mistake).

Comment: Also, d.show > I want the image to appear for the user. So I don't what to just print the random file name.

Comment: You just have to change the string to a mac os style path.
With '/Users/<yourusername>' you get to your home directory.
With './folder' you access a folder named folder in your current directory.

Comment: @user13590849 To show the image, you can use tkinter, or PIL.

Comment: @HackLab OMG!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!! IT WORKED! I CAN'T THANK YOU ENOUGH!!1